# Disable CSS animation on page resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sprite animation that occurs when a checkbox is checked (using the :checked pseudo -- so really 'if' a checkbox is checked). I have a breakpoint at 640px that hides the checkbox. The issue is that when the page is resized to less than 640px wide, and the checkbox is already checked, the animation plays. I only want the animation to occur as a result of the user checking the checkbox.

I tried using a resize event listener w/ a timeout to stop the animation, but as soon as the user stops resizing the page, the animation plays. Here is the css that performs the animation:

```
@include bp-mobile {  /*this is the query that sets the max-width to 640px */
.toggler:checked ~.group {
        visibility: visible;  /* otherwise not visible */
        transform: translateX(0px);
        animation: menuPatch 175ms steps(8);
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-delay: 50ms;
    }
}
```

I should probably point out that the group class is a ul, and the background image on that ul is the sprite that's being animated. I'm trying to make two menus one for a mobile layout and one for desktop. for the mobile layout, I want the menu to be toggleable, and the animation to occur only once when it's toggled.

If I had to guess what's happening it would be this: if the menu is open (.toggler:checked) and the user resizes the page to less than 640px, the css sees that the toggle is checked, and plays the animation (because any screen larger than 640px would have the toggle visibility set to 'hidden', and no styling would be applied otherwise). How can I stop this without using any frameworks?

Comment: Presumably in your CSS comment you mean min-width rather than max-width? Have you tried with media queries to set it as display:none with media query of max-width i.e. targeting smaller screens separately?

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to this thing -- maybe could've explained it better. You're right I meant max-width, as in the .toggler class (the checkbox) will have its visibility set to 'visible' when the user resizes the page to less than 640px wide. So if I set a display:none on that min-width query, then I presume the user wouldn't be able to see the animation at all when checking the box. The issue is really on resize between the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving my @keyframes rule and the above code outside of the media query, and that did the trick -- even if the toggle visibility is set to hidden.

```
/* for any screen size */
.toggler:checked ~.group {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    animation: menuPatch 175ms steps(8);
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 50ms;
}

 /* Mobile Menu Background */
    .group {
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
    @include bp-mobile {     /* stuff I need to happen to the ul for mobile */
        background-image: url(../pictures/mobile-sprite.png);
        background-position-x: right; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-top: 60px;
        padding: 20px;
        padding-top: 80px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 200px;
        height: 341px;
        transform: translateX(-200px);
    }
        @keyframes menuPatch {
            from {
                background-position-x: 0px;
            }
            to {
                background-position-x: -1600px;
            }
        }
    
        /* End mobile menu background */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove visibility hidden and move the toggle out of the view area for more than 640px . For the screen less than 640px you could bring back the toggler. This would help to play animation but not visible on the screen for screens more than 640px.

```css
// For less than 640px
.toggler:checked~.group {
  transform: translateX(0px);
  animation: menuPatch 175ms steps(8);
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 50ms;
}

.toggler~.group {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1000px;
}
```